# How do I properly handle a remote link to in Rails 4? JSON?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following code:

```
= link_to "#{icon('heart')} Props".html_safe, vote_picture_path(picture), class: 'tiny radius secondary button vote', method: :put, remote: true
```

Which goes here:

```
  # VOTE /pictures/1.json
  def vote
    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.toggle_vote(current_user)
        format.json { render json: @picture }
      else
        format.json { render json: @picture }
      end
    end
  end
```

And what I'm trying to do is update the total count of votes on a picture via:

```
$ ->
  $(".vote").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    vote_count_size = $(".vote-count .size").html()
    vote_count_size_integer = parseInt(vote_count_size)
    console.info data
```

However the part that confuses me is the console.info data. It seems to be returning something from a source I can't tell. I'm editing /pictures/show.json.jbuilder but it's not affecting what's coming in from data. I want to return a json structure with the total votes in data so I can update the count on the page from the success callback.

Comment: Can you try `bind` instead of `on`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should respond with a javascript file (vote.js.erb) within this you can mix javascript and erb expressions to change the desired page element:

```
$('.vote-count .size').html('<%=@picture.vote_count%> votes');
```

your controller would look like:

```
# VOTE /pictures/1.js
def vote
  respond_to do |format|
    @picture.toggle_vote(current_user)
    format.js 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `respond_to` block can be refactored dramatically:

```
  # VOTE /pictures/1.json
  respond_to :json

  def vote
     @picture.toggle_vote(current_user)
     respond_with @picture
  end
```

This should return a JSON object for your `@picture` var. You'll have to detail what data you're getting in your `console`? If you provide the data you're receiving back, it will be a huge help!

Comment: It's returning back this: https://gist.github.com/ecl1pse/ea0fb3936d2ca911e311 which I have no clue how because if I edit what's in pictures/show.jbuilder it doesn't affect this.

Comment: not sure if you need any more information to get this work? My confusion is should I even be doing it this way?